# Why stemDocument change an ending 'y' to 'i'? How to stop it?

Tags: r, nlp, tm

When using stemDocument{SnowBallC} in R, I found it would change a letter 'y' at then end of a word to letter 'i', for example:

```
> stemDocument('sleepy', language='english')
[1] "sleepi"
```

I'm wondering how can we prevent this in stemming?

Thanks,
Ming

Answer (score 2):

The hunspell package has a better stemmer:

```
> library(hunspell)
> hunspell_stem("sleepy", dict = "en_US")
[[1]]
[1] "sleepy"

> hunspell_analyze("sleepy", dict = "en_US")
[[1]]
[1] " st:sleepy"
```